# Sobrecarga de registros en archivo access.log en servidor XAMPP

Tags: web, apache, xampp, servidor

Tengo una duda sobre el archivo access.log que se localiza dentro del servidor XAMPP, he notado que el archivo crece demasiado y alenta un poco mi servidor  ¿es recomendable borrar estos registros o es normal que el archivo crezca con estos registros?

Agradezco sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

Ahí se registran todas las solicitudes procesadas por el servidor. Si quieres lo puedes eliminar y crear otro con los mismos permisos, luego reiniciar el servidor apache, pero la opción (a pie) usual es la siguiente, la cual la voy a describir en un script.

```
#!/bin/bash

: << __docstring__

    Tienes que correr este script como superusuario para modificar los archivos, 
    cambiar permisos y propietarios, y reiniciar el servidor.

__docstring__


directorio_apache="<directorio_logs>"  #  Pon aqui el directorio donde tengas los logs
access_log=$directorio_apache/access.log

n_ultimo_archivo=$(
    find "$directorio_apache" -maxdepth 1 -name "access.log.*.gz" 2> /dev/null | cut -d '.' -f 4  | sort -n | tail -n1
    [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 1 ]] && echo 0
)  #  "Calculas" el ultimo respaldo hecho por este script, ya sea con el numero mas grande de los
   #+ archivos de la forma "access.log.n.gz" o si no hay ninguno de esa forma lo define como "0"
   #+ para posteriormente incrementarlo en 1.

last_access_log=$access_log.$((++n_ultimo_archivo))  #  Creas el nombre "access.log.n+1" para cambiar el nombre
mv $access_log $last_access_log                      #+ del archivo access.log a este nuevo archivo.

touch $access_log   #  Posteriormente creas un nuevo archivo access.log vacio
                    #+ y le cambias los permisos y el dueño y grupo identicos
                    #+ a los que tenia el primer archivo access.log

printf 'chmod\nchown' | xargs -I {} bash -c '{} --reference=$last_access_log $access_log'
#  ^^^^  Toda esta linea es mi forma presuntuosa de cambiar 
#+       tanto dueno como grupo en, estrictamente, una sola linea.
#+       Puedes hacerlo de comando por comando.

service apache2 restart  #  Reinicias el servidor apache y asi ya no tienes que esperar a que termine
                         #+ de comprimir.

gzip --to-stdout --best $last_access_log > $last_access_log.gz  #  Se comprime el archivo de los logs creando
                                                                #+ un archivo .gz

rm $last_access_log  #  Borras el archivo de logs que no esta
                     #+ comprimido.
```

La otra opción, que creo que es la más usada en entornos de producción, es que utilices `logrotate`.

https://serverfault.com/questions/357928/apache-log-files-getting-too-big-how-do-i-make-it-save-on-a-per-day-basis

Pero teniendo en consideración lo mencionado por @rexkogitans en la siguiente publicación.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832743/access-log-is-huge-not-being-archived-how-to-reset-it